# Postgres SQL pqxx Error while writing a program in C++

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, csv

I am trying to parse a 1001 line CSV file that has 43 total attributes. My end result should be a table that has 43 attributes, and 1000 tuples. I want my program to skip over the first line, before the first line is just the headers (and not needed). The CSV has the following format:

Line 1: HOUSEID,VARSTRAT,WTHHFIN,DRVRCNT,CDIVMSAR,CENSUS_D,CENSUS_R,HH_HISP,HH_RACE,HHFAMINC,HHRELATD,HHRESP,HHSIZE,HHSTATE,HHSTFIPS,HHVEHCNT,HOMEOWN,HOMETYPE,MSACAT,MSASIZE,NUMADLT,RAIL,RESP_CNT,SCRESP,TRAVDAY,URBAN,URBANSIZE,URBRUR,WRKCOUNT,TDAYDATE,FLAG100,LIF_CYC,CNTTDHH,HBHUR,HTRESDN,HTHTNRNT,HTPPOPDN,HTEEMPDN,HBRESDN,HBHTNRNT,HBPPOPDN,HH_CBSA,HHC_MSA

The rest of the lines:

Line2:
20000017,48,264.19469357,2,33,03,02,02,01,18,-1,02,3,IN,18,3,01,01,03,03,3,02,3,-1,04,04,06,02,1,200904,01,10,13,TC,300,5,300,75,300,5,300,XXXXX,XXXX

Line 3: (same format)

Line 4: (same format)
etc.

Line 1000:
The goal of my code is to store each line inside line, and then parse that line to grab each attribute to store in the string, "column". Then after, each line, i reset the count to be equal to 1. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace pqxx;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  string user_name = getenv("USER");
  string host = "/home/" + user_name + "/postgres";
  string connection_string = "dbname=postgres user=" + user_name + " host=" +            host + " port=5432";
  connection C(connection_string.c_str());

  if (C.is_open()) 
  {
    cout << "Database was opened successfully: " << C.dbname() << endl;
  }
  else 
  {
    cout << "Database couldn't be opened" << endl;
    return 1;
  }
  /* database openeed */
  string HHV2PUB = "CREATE TABLE HOUSEHOLD(HOUSEID INT, VARSTRAT INT, WTHHFIN   DOUBLE PRECISION,   DRVRCNT INT, CDIVMSAR INT, CENSUS_D INT, CENSUS_R INT, HH_HISP INT, HH_RACE INT, HHFAMINC INT, HHRELATD INT, HHRESP INT, HHSIZE INT, HHSTATE CHAR(2), HHSTFIPS INT, HHVEHCNT INT, HOMEOWN INT, HOMETYPE INT, MSACAT INT, MSASIZE INT, NUMADLT INT, RAIL INT, RESP_CNT INT, SCRESP INT, TRAVDAY INT, URBAN INT, URBANSIZE INT, URBRUR INT, WRKCOUNT INT, TDAYDATE INT, FLAG100 INT, LIF_CYC INT, CNTTDHH INT, HBHUR VARCHAR(2), HTRESDN INT, HTHTNRNT INT, HTPPOPDN INT, HTEEMPDN INT, HBRESDN INT, HBHTNRNT INT, HBPPOPDN INT, HH_CBSA INT, HHC_MSA INT);";



  ifstream inputFile("HHV2PUB.CSV");
  string line;
  string line1;
  std::getline(inputFile, line1);
  string blah("\'*\'"); //DO I NEED THESE?????
  string blah2("1337");
  string blah3("9999");
  string sql; 

  while (std::getline(inputFile, line))
  {
    int count = 1;
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);
    string column;
    sql = "INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD VALUES (";
    while (std::getline(lineStream, column, ','))
    {
      cout << count << endl;
      if (count == 14 || count == 34) 
      {
        if (count != 34) 
        { //count == 14
          sql += "\'";
          sql += column;
          sql += "\'";
          count++;
          sql+= ", ";
          continue;
        }
        else 
        { //count == 34
          if (column[0] == '-' && column[1] == '9' && count == 34)
          { 
            sql+= blah;
            count++;
            sql+= ", ";
            continue;
          }
          else if (count == 34) 
          {
            sql+= "\'";
            sql+= column;
            sql += "\'";
            count++;
            sql+= ", ";
            continue;
          }
        }
      }
      if ((column == "XXXXX") && (count == 42)) 
      {
        cout << "dddd" << endl;
        sql+= blah2;
        count++;
        sql+= ", ";
        continue;
      }

      if (count == 43) { cout << column << endl;}
      cout << "cccccccccccccc" << endl; 
      if ((column == "XXXX") && (count == 43)) //WHY DOESN"T IT ENTER HERE? BOH CONDITIONS ARE TRUE BUT PROGRAM DOESNT GO IN HERE.
      {
        cout << "HELLLLO" << endl;
        sql+= blah3;
        count++;
        cout << "Count is " << count << endl;
        continue;
      }
      //else if (count == 43) 
      //{
      //  sql+= column;
      //  count++;
      //  continue;
        // dont append the ","
      //}
      sql += column;
      count++;
      sql += ", ";
      continue; 
    }
    cout << sql << endl;
    if (count == 44) 
    {
      cout << "***********************" << endl; 
      sql+= "); "; 
      //count = 1;
    }
    //cout << count << endl;
    //cout << sql << endl;
    work W(C);
    W.exec(sql);
    W.commit();  
  }
  C.disconnect(); 
  return 0;
}
```

"Output: 
[kcheng94@pc12 Ascii]$ a.out
Database was opened successfully: postgres
1
cccccccccccccc
2
cccccccccccccc
3
cccccccccccccc
4
cccccccccccccc
5
cccccccccccccc
6
cccccccccccccc
7
cccccccccccccc
8
cccccccccccccc
9
cccccccccccccc
10
cccccccccccccc
11
cccccccccccccc
12
cccccccccccccc
13
cccccccccccccc
14
15
cccccccccccccc
16
cccccccccccccc
17
cccccccccccccc
18
cccccccccccccc
19
cccccccccccccc
20
cccccccccccccc
21
cccccccccccccc
22
cccccccccccccc
23
cccccccccccccc
24
cccccccccccccc
25
cccccccccccccc
26
cccccccccccccc
27
cccccccccccccc
28
cccccccccccccc
29
cccccccccccccc
30
cccccccccccccc
31
cccccccccccccc
32
cccccccccccccc
33
cccccccccccccc
34
35
cccccccccccccc
36
cccccccccccccc
37
cccccccccccccc
38
cccccccccccccc
39
cccccccccccccc
40
cccccccccccccc
41
cccccccccccccc
42
dddd
43
XXXX
cccccccccccccc
INSERT INTO HOUSEHOLD VALUES (20000017, 48, 264.19469357, 2, 33, 03, 02, 02, 01, 18, -1, 02, 3, 'IN', 18, 3, 01, 01, 03, 03, 3, 02, 3, -1, 04, 04, 06, 02, 1, 200904, , , 10, 13, 'TC', 300, 5, 300, 75, 300, 5, 300, 1337, XXXX

---

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pqxx::syntax_error'
  what():  ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 2: , ); "
          ^

Abort (core dumped)
Why am i getting a core dumped? Also, why is there a random comma "," between 200904 and 10? I don't know why my program never goes into the body of the If statement, even though the test condition is true, as evident in the output. Thank you very much for looking at my post.

Comment: Why doesn't my program go into the IF statement body? Column == XXXX and count == 43 is true

Comment: Strong advice to rewrite your `if else if else` chain into a switch (`continue;` still works inside a switch)